# Navigation Drawer implies nested fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I created an application with a navigation drawer navigating following the android documentation tutorial. Now the main parts of my application are Fragment but the problem is I have to use dynamic fragments in one of them. 
I saw the nested fragments were supported since android 4.2, but I need to use my app on older version.

What can I do ? 
I'm thinking of using a FrameLayout of fixed fragments and to set them visible or gone depending of what I need, but it seems a little ugly...

What do you think ?
Thanks for your answers

Edit : 
my question is not clear but what I want to know is :

- can I use the navigationdrawer with activities instead of fragments ?
- is the solution I'm thinking about realy ugly ?
- how can I use the nested fragment system for older version ?

Comment: you can have framelayout as a container add or replace fragments when you want

Comment: You can also use the Android Support Library. It also supports nested fragments for older Android versions. See here: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

Comment: "What do you think ?" -- I think that this question is unclear. What specifically is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used the nested fragment system using the Android Support Library (thanks Nobu Games) 
Thanks for your comments